# Trouble Generating Publicly Accessible URL for Uploaded Images in Django App

Tags: python, django, webserver, replicate

I'm currently working on a Django application hosted locally that accepts user-uploaded images. The images are stored successfully, but I'm facing challenges in generating a publicly accessible URL for these uploaded images. The ultimate goal is to feed this URL into the replicate.com API endpoint.

Here's a brief overview of my process:

1. User uploads an image via the Django app.
2. The image is stored locally on the server.
3. Need to generate a publicly accessible URL for the uploaded image.
   views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
import replicate
from .forms import ImageUploadForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            image_instance = request.FILES['image']
            file_url = handle_uploaded_file(image_instance)
            response = run_replicate(file_url)
            output_url = response[0]
            context = {'output_url': output_url}
            return render(request, 'core/results.html', context)

    else:
        form = ImageUploadForm()

    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(uploaded_file):
    os.makedirs('images/new', exist_ok=True)
    file_path = os.path.join('images/new', uploaded_file.name)
    with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    file_url = file_path.replace("\\", "/")
    file_url = "https://replit.com/@mashudhassandev/ChatgptImgGen#" + file_url
    return file_url
  

def run_replicate(file_content):
  model_id = 'jagilley/controlnet-canny:aff48af9c68d162388d230a2ab003f68d2638d88307bdaf1c2f1ac95079c9613'
  response = replicate.run(
      model_id,
      input={
          'image': open(file_content, "rb"),
          'prompt': 'hyperrealistic portrait, photograph, real person'
      })
  
  return response
```

How can I effectively create a publicly accessible URL for the uploaded images in Django? Any insights, code snippets, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.